# Flutter-Firebase: Not able to create firebase project from terminal

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

```
i Found 1 Firebase projects.

✔ Select a Firebase project to configure your Flutter application with · <create a new project> 

✔ Enter a project id for your new Firebase project (e.g. my-cool-project) · first-trial-proj 

i New Firebase project first-trial-proj created succesfully.
```

> FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
>
> COMMAND: `firebase projects:create first-trial-proj --json`
>
> ERROR: Failed to create project because there is already a project with ID first-trial-proj. Please try again with a unique project ID-----

This is what happens when I try to create a firebase project. Also I don't know why it accepted `"in-demo-proj"` as the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project names in Firebase and Google Cloud have to be globally unique amongst all users. The error message seems to indicate that a project named `first-trial-proj` already exists.

You might want to try something a but more likely to be unique, like a combination of your name and the date.

Alternatively, you can first create the project in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) (which performs such checks for uniqueness as you type) and only then run the FlutterFire CLI and *select* the project.